# How to write a if statement inside of a php variable that has html in it

Tags: php, html

I have a php variable that is given a html tag .
I need to have a php if condition inside that tag, here I what is have down:

```
$var = "<textarea"  *if ($i=="1") { echo 'something' }* "id=\"id\" </textarea>";
```

What is the proper format to do this?

Comment: Use single quotes as well, you won't have to escape the double ones then.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because this is something that can often be learned on your own when first learning PHP or that there is already enough relevant information on the internet to not need to ask Stackoverflow.  Just a guess though, I didn't down vote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either build up in stages:

```
$var = "<textarea";
if ($i=="1"){
    $var .= 'something';
}
$var .= "id=\"id\" </textarea>";
```

Or use a ternary operator:

```
$var = "<textarea" . ($i=="1" ? 'something' : '' ) . "id=\"id\" </textarea>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = "<textarea" . ($i=="1" ? "something" : "") . "id=\"id\" </textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work like this

```
$var = '<textarea ' . (($i=="1") ?  'something' : '') .  ' id="id" </textarea>';
```